create-react-appを使用するのではなくReact フレームワークを使用してReactのプロジェクトをつくるとは？
React公式を参考に簡単なプロジェクトを作成してみようと思っています。
https://ja.react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project
こちらを見ると「React だけで新しいアプリやウェブサイトを作りたい場合は、コミュニティで人気のある React フレームワークから、ひとつを選ぶことをおすすめします」とあり、 create-react-app でプロジェクトを作成するのではなく、Next.jsの create-next-app やRemixの create-remix などでのプロジェクトを作成を勧められているようです。
なんとなく聞き覚えがあるNext.jsを選択し create-next-app コマンドを使用すると簡単にプロジェクトが作成され、npm run dev を実行するとブラウザ表示されました。
ただ、この場合作成されたプロジェクトはNext.jsだと思うのですが、Reactの公式で書かれている「React だけで新しいアプリやウェブサイトを作りたい場合」はここからどのように進めていきなさいよ、ということなのでしょうか？
上記サイトのインストールの章をひととおり読んでみたのですが、理解できません。
何かアドバイスいただけると助かります。

公式ドキュメントに書かれている「React だけで新しいアプリやウェブサイトを作りたい場合」は、おそらく以下のような選択肢のツリーを念頭に置いていると思います。

「React だけで新しいアプリやウェブサイトを作りたい場合」

（公式の推奨、目指している理想）React ベースのフレームワークを使用する（Next.js, Remix, Astro(?), Redwood など）
フレームワーク無しで開発するためのスターターを使う（create-vite-app）

create-react-app は開発が一時的に滞っているので、非推奨です。




別の言語・フレームワークで開発されたフルスタックアプリの一部にReactを組み込む

Laravel の Blade とか？



ただ、あくまでも理想形なので、各種フレームワーク（特に Next.js）が設計の試行錯誤を繰り返している今の時点では、「フレームワークの学習が大変なので、とりあえず create-vite-app ではじめてみる」という選択肢は十分にあると思います。
